# Typed collection with Open Type Parameter

Tags: c#, collections, typed

I want to know why I am getting error if I write the below statement although I have mention at class level what is T

```
IList<T> targetObjectsCollection = new List<T>();
for (int counter = 0;  counter < dataTransferObjects.Count; counter++)
{
    targetObjectsCollection.Add(MappSharePointDAOToDTO(sharePointDaos[counter], dataTransferObjects[counter]));
}
```

and when I changed it to the following statement error has gone??

```
IList<IMapperMarker> targetObjectsCollection = new List<IMapperMarker>();
for (int counter = 0;  counter < dataTransferObjects.Count; counter++)
{
    targetObjectsCollection.Add(MappSharePointDAOToDTO(sharePointDaos[counter], dataTransferObjects[counter]));
}
```

can any body describe.

Comment: What language is this?  Looks like C# but could also be Java with questionable naming conventions...

Comment: I'd lean closer to C# than Java.  There's no property `Count` on a List.

Comment: @Makoto That's true and consistent with what I was thinking.  I'm retagging.  If it's wrong the OP can retag as Java

Comment: What did you define at class level? Can see see the class declaration line?

Answer (score 3):

You do not seem to have defined `T`. It's a placeholder. It requires definition.

This code might work if it were used in a context where `T` had a definition. For instance,

```
private IList<T> AddDataTransferObjects(IList<T> dataTransferObjects)
    : where T : IMapperMarker
{
    IList<T> targetObjectsCollection = new List<T>();
    for (int counter = 0;  counter < dataTransferObjects.Count; counter++)
    {
        targetObjectsCollection.Add(MappSharePointDAOToDTO(sharePointDaos[counter], dataTransferObjects[counter]));
    }
    return targetObjectsCollection;
}
```

If you called that like this as follows:

```
IList<IMapperMarker> dtoList = Something();
var list = AddDataTransferObjects(dtoList);
```

In this case, the inner `T` would be bound to the type `IMapperMarker`.

Comment: For your example, i think `targetObjectsCollection.Add` would still be unhappy, unless you also added the constraint `where T : IMapperMarker` to the function.